# Azure DevOPs Pipeline Variable using a variable syntax

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Straightforward. if you know the Syntax I have googled to no avail, so it may not be possible.

To avoid multiple variable updates, in Octopus I used nested variables I am converting to Azure DevOps Pipeline but cannot find the syntax

Octopus Variables used:-

```
e.g variable 1 - my.VirtualDirectory, Value - Website2018 
    variable 2 - TargetDatabasename, Value - #{my.VirtualDirectory}_DB_Checking
    variable 3 - TargetDatabasename, Value - #{my.VirtualDirectory}_DB_Checked
```

the #{} allowed a nested variable, can anyone help with the syntax for Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its `$()` in ADO. same goes for nested: `bla-bla-$()-bla`

if you are using yaml you can also do this:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@3
  inputs:
    omitted for brievity
    Inline: |
        ${{ format('. $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\scripts\_helpers.ps1
        Update-DeploymentPrereq -resourceGroup {1} -location {3}
        Update-Prereq -pathSuffix {0} -pathBase $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) -resourceGroup {1} -buildId $(Build.BuildNumber) -paramFile {2}
        Update-DeploymentConcurrency -resourceGroup {1} -buildId $(Build.BuildNumber)',
            parameters.buildDir, parameters.resourceGroupName, parameters.paramFile, parameters.location ) }}
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```